# Static variables strange behavior in android

Tags: android, static

i am facing a problem, very strange problem.

When i update any one static variable within a class then the other static variables in the class also got updated, don't know why this is happening.

please help me out, i don't even know what to do with this problem.

this line creating problem.

```
private static cSet currentSet = new cSet();
private static cSet currentPracticeSet = new cSet();
    public static void setCurrentPracticeSetRange(int from, int to)
{
    Log.e(currentPracticeSet.getCards().size()+" And "+currentSet.getCards().size(), to+" and "+from);
    getCurrentPracticeSet().getCards().clear();
    getCurrentPracticeSet().getCards().addAll(getCurrentSet().getCards().subList(from, to));

    Log.e("Range",currentSet.getCards().size()+"");
}
```

currentSet and CurrentPracticeSet are the private static member of class.
Thanks,

Comment: That's what `static` means.

Comment: That's better, but we still need to see your `static` variable declarations.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know.  If I were to guess I'd say you're setting `currentSet` to `currentPracticeSet` (or vice versa) somewhere in your code.  If you do that, the two variables now *point to the same set.*

Comment: @RobertHarvey why they are point to same set, set is just a class defined my me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static means that the scope of a variable is bounded by the class, not the object. If you change the value in one, they're all going to change.

Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413898/what-does-the-static-keyword-do-in-a-class) for more info.

Comment: `static` means that the variable is scoped to the class definition.  It's not really an "instance," as such.

Comment: @RobertHarvey i know about static that why i am using them. but this is strange that you have 2 static variables in one class, when you change in one variable then the other variable got updated also.

Comment: @AhmadRaza: Show us your code containing your variable declarations. My guess is you have an error in your code that is erroneously setting both variables.

Comment: @AhmadRaza: You still haven't shown us your static variables.  We need to see those.